# clock() just returns 0

Tags: c++, linux, g++, clock

[The C `clock()` function just returns a zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134363/10982941)

[clock() function always returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11976342/10982941)

[why C clock() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9871071/10982941)

I looked up all these questions and answers

And I learned that clock() returns clock ticks per some constant which differs per systems

And time() returns the number of seconds.

First, I was trying to measure the execution time of my sorting algorithm using clock() like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

... Some other headers and codes

a = clock();
exchange_sort();
a = clock() - a;

... Rest of the code
```

I tried many different data types with a like int, clock_t, long, float.
And I sorted a pretty big size array `int arr[1000]` with already increased order.
But the value of `a` was always 0, so I tried to find the reason using gdb and I set a breakpoint to the line where the sorting algorithm is located so that I can check the value of `a = clock();` and there has to be some number inside the variable but there was only 0.

So after that, I tried to check whether the function was the problem itself or something else like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a;
    clock_t b;
    float c;
    long d;
    a = clock();
    b = clock();
    c = clock();
    d = clock();
    return 0;
}
```

And I checked the value of each variable through gdb and there were just garbage numbers before I put the return value of `clock()` but after I put there were only 0s inside the variables.
So apparently `clock()` just returns 0 all the time in my conclusion

I really don't know how can I fix this

My g++ version is 4.4.7. 
I ran this in Linux
My processor is x86_64-redhat-linux

Comment: possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178789/c-different-implementation-of-clock-in-windows-and-other-os

Comment: I would recommend using [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) instead and getting yourself a more modern compiler (for example by installing [devtoolset-8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/8/html/8.0_release_notes/dts8.0_release)).

Comment: @Lock-not-gimbal thanks for the clue! I should read that in detail

Comment: @JesperJuhl I just knew about the function! Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: Different implementation of clock() in Windows and other OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178789/c-different-implementation-of-clock-in-windows-and-other-os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clock()` function is a coarse measure of CPU time used. Your code doesn't use enough CPU time to measure with such a coarse measure. You should probably switch to something like `getrusage` instead.

Comment: Thanks!! So then does everyone get 0 when they call clock() right at the beginning of the main function?

Comment: @Thankyouforanswering On most platforms with most code, yes, since you haven't used much CPU time yet.

Answer (score 1):

My code used enough CPU time. But it seems the clock is only ticking with a step of 15625ms.[image: Elapsed time]

My advice is to use `<chrono>` instead.